# Evaluating $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n(1-e^{an})} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know if a closed form exists, but if it does, I'd like to know:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n(1-e^{an})} $$

for $a>0$ - assume that the value of $a$ is such that the denominator is always non-zero.

"Attempt" at a solution: this seems to be useful:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1-a^n} = \frac{\psi_{1/a}(1) + \ln(a-1) - \ln a}{\ln a}$$

where $\psi_q$ is the $q$-digamma function.

Comment: Where does this series come from?

Comment: Tough to explain, but essentially approximating solutions to master equations

Comment: Are you sure it is $e^{an}$ and not $e^{\color{red}{-}an}$?

Comment: Yes. But also, I'm not sure if your version converges

Comment: It seems like there would be a problem at $n=1$ if $a=\ln 2$ (and probably others).  Such problems might mean that a closed form would be out of reach...

Comment: You're right, I did not define the range of permissible $a$ correctly